# Someone tried to log into my mail - what do I do?

Tags: multi-factor

I have a 2-step verification system for both my gmail accounts. Today, I received a message with a code when I **wasn't trying to log in**.

So someone has my password. What's my next step here? What should I do?

Comment: I would guess... change it?

Comment: @iismathwizard yeah yeah I mean other than that. Can I see from where the sign in was attempted? Should I notify Google somehow?

Comment: To see recently signed in devices: https://myaccount.google.com/security#signin

Comment: @iismathwizard odd... I don't see anything weird there

Comment: Do you use your password elsewhere? Probably best to change them too if you do...

Answer (score 4):

Change your password. Keep a strong password. Change your security question as some one close to you can easily guess the answer and get the access to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Scan you system with a virus scanner since you don't know how they obtained your password. Change the password for all accounts since all of your passwords may be compromised, either through the same malware or through password recovery by logging into your e-mail.

Some webservices allow you to look at login attempts (successful and unsuccessful) and give an IP-address. whereis can tell you something about the location but normally such an attacker will use a proxy or the tor network to avoid detection. You can however monitor these login attempts to see which other accounts might be compromised.

Comment: I would go as far as to change all passwords for all systems since you don't know what passwords they have access to now

Comment: True, but I'm guessing that the person won't even change the accounts with the compromised password due to to much work. But indeed, you can assume that everything is compromised.

If you have malware you should trow away your hard drive. Since any program can be infected and not all malware might be detected by a virusscanner. I'm just saying what the bare minimum is that he should do.

Comment: Silver, l think putting the best practices in your answer is best. You can add weaker options if you feel it's appropriate. Answers should be authoritative.

Comment: @Silver honestly throwing away your harddrive is a little excessive unless you happen to work for a high profile company or are a high profile target yourself. I wouldn't expect the average user to come across malware sophisticated enough to not be detectable by consumer accessible levels of malware detection and removal tools. I'd use malwarebytes and kaspersky and see if anything comes up.

Answer (score 0):

**What to do:**

1. Change password. Change all of your associated passwords too.
2. Install a good antivirus software.
3. Check if there are any keyloggers in your computer or if you have used the account on any public systems.
4. Check the mail settings to find the location of login.
5. Do not write or disclose any passwords, hints, texts or images.

Answer (score -1):

Best thing to do is changed your password and use the Google authenicator on your phone and there is an option where you have to type your Google Auth form your phone  which is real good I suggest that. Also if your using a computer or phone to login your email scan for virus and malware just to be safe

Comment: This answer is very incoherent. Could you rewrite it to make it more clear?